# "First thing I did" vs "First thing I have done"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the simple past and present perfect in the following?

> When I first got here, I bought a car. [Assuming I still own the car]. This is the first thing I have done.
>
> When I first got here, I bought a car. [Assuming I still own the car]. This is the first thing I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause *when I first got here* is an expression of finished time (cf. *yesterday, last week*), and requires the past simple. So your first sentence in ungrammatical. If, on the other hand, you use an expression of unfinished time, you usually use the present perfect:

> Since I first got here, I have bought a new car, found a job, got married, etc.

The difference is between the words *when* (finished time - past simple) and *since* (unfinished time - present perfect).

Comment: Thanks. Why do the grammar books say that we use present perfect if it's our first experience? Not sure if I am explaining it properly.

Comment: @Noah, When you first announce something you often you the present perfect: *I've bought a new car*. But as soon as you use an expression of past time, you must use the past simple: *I bought a new car yesterday.*

Comment: Last question. Is the simple present in the first part of this sentence correct? "This **is** the first thing I did." Or should it be "was"?

Comment: @Noah, Short answer: Both *This is the first thing I did* and *This was the first thing I did* are correct and common.